# Why cannot C# compiler implicitly infer `Foo foo = (int x) => x.ToString();` for the delegate type `static delegate R Foo<I, R>(I i);`?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static delegate R Foo<I, R>(I i);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Foo<int, string> foo = (int x) => x.ToString();

        // Why can't the compiler IMPLICITLY infer the following declaration?
        //Foo foo = (int x) => x.ToString();
    }
}
```

EDIT 1: The code above is not compilable actually. The delegate I defined has static modifier that is not applicable!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't about type inference, it's because there's no such type as `Foo`. (`Foo<I,R>` and `Foo`, if it existed, are two completely different types as far as the compiler is concerned.)

For the same reason you can't legally do any of the following:

```
Dictionary d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
List l = new List<string>();
Func f = new Func<int, string>(i => i.ToString());
```

Comment: damn, nearly the same first sentence :D

Comment: I feel this is the answer I want. Thanks for your answer. Thanks other participants for their answers. Great!

Answer (score 3):

Because Foo is not a type that has been defined, but Foo<,> is a type that has been defined.

*Removed `var` suggestion as it doesn't work...

Comment: If I change to var, I will get "Cannot assign lamba expression to an implicitly-typed local variable (var)" :-)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You're right, the compiler isn't as good as inference when it comes to lambdas; I've run into that before.  There's probably a good reason for it, but I don't know the exact answer.  The explanation as to why your first attempt doesn't work still stands though.  There may have been some purpose lost when you simplified your code, but with the advent of Action<> and Func<> there are fewer and fewer reasons to define delegates yourself (though they do still serve their purpose). (Also editing out the var suggestion since it doesn't work).

Answer (score 2):

C# spec states that lambdas are *untyped* constructs (like *method groups*).  They can be *converted* to compatible types.  For this reason, you can't write `var something = (SomeType a) => a;`

The rationale is they can be interpreted as expression trees and delegates depending on the context.  There's no way to know which one is your intent outside a specific context.  You cannot use a lambda expression or method group outside a context in which they can be converted to something.

> #### C# Language Specification v4.0 (§1.4.12)
>
> #### Anonymous function conversions and method group conversions
>
> Anonymous functions and method groups do not have types in and of themselves, but may be implicitly converted to delegate types or expression tree types. Anonymous function conversions are described in more detail in §1.44 and method group conversions in §1.45.

Comment: I will review this answer later because I have no idea about the terminologies explained above. But it is a good answer of course!

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no such type `Foo`. If declaring a variable of a certain type, you have to define its generic parameters as well.

Answer (score 1):

In example, this works fine:

```
F((int x) => x.ToString());     
private static void F<I,R>(Foo<I, R> foo)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a small wrapper class.

```
static class Foo {
    public static Foo<I, R> Create<I, R>(Foo<I, R> foo) {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Then this works fine:

```
var foo = Foo.Create((int x) => x.ToString());
```